# JQuery Change style of some td elements on drop/sort of table row

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to JQuery, and as usual, want to do something esoteric ;-)

I'd like to change the style (to make visible/hidden) some of the TD elements of a row when it is dragged into another sortable table.

I've seen some examples of changing the whole row, but that's not what I want.

I have a receive event setup; I just don't know how to identify individual TDs and change their style...

```
receive: function (event, ui) {
   if (this.id == "table-body-included") {
      // change style of some TDs to ""
   }
   else {
      // change style of some TDs to "display:none"
   }
}
```

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Why don't you just do it with CSS?? Why is jQuery needed?

Comment: JQuery is already in use on this page (it is MVC).

Comment: Also, I only want to change a few TD elements, not all of them, and at different times.

Comment: So you can not add classes to the cells and toggle a CSS rule on the table that show and hides them?

Comment: That would affect ALL rows/TDs that have that class, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 receive: function (event, ui) {
            if ($(this).is("#table-body-included")) {
                // change style of some TDs to ""
            }
            else {
               // change style of some TDs to "display:none"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the situation...
Not ideal, I know, and not very pretty, but it works:

```
if ($(this).is("#table-body-included")) {
    ui.item[0].childNodes[11].hidden = false;
    ui.item[0].childNodes[13].hidden = false;
    ui.item[0].childNodes[15].hidden = false;
    ui.item[0].childNodes[17].hidden = false;
}
else {
    ui.item[0].childNodes[11].hidden = true;
    ui.item[0].childNodes[13].hidden = true;
    ui.item[0].childNodes[15].hidden = true;
    ui.item[0].childNodes[17].hidden = true;
}
```